# Excel - Lookup Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup

I am unable to return a lookup value, obtaining either #VALUE! or #N/A! error.

Here is the screenshot of worksheet layout:
[image]

**Question: How do I return the "HONOURS" value in cell N3?**

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post your formula that returns an error. Also is calculation of honors value based on column L value? In principle, a formula like `=VLOOKUP(L3,$E$3:$G$8,3,TRUE)` shall work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! I used - =XLOOKUP($N$2,$E$2:$G$2,XLOOKUP(M3,$E$3:$E$8,$G$3:$G$8))                                    The calculation of honors value is based on Column M's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `XLOOKUP()` formula. Here `match_mode` 1 will search for exact match or next larger item in array.

```
=XLOOKUP(L3,$F$3:$F$8,$G$3:$G$8,"",1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me! I edited it to --> =XLOOKUP(M3,$E$3:$E$8,$G$3:$G$8,"",1)